# Does Azure App Service support ASP.NET 4.6.1 version?

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment, service, paas

I need to deploy n ASP.NET 4.6.1 application into Azure App Service. Currently only ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.8 seem to be available options in the Azure portal. Is this a hard requirement, i.e. is it mandatory to update my ASP.NET solutions to 4.8 version prior to deploying to Azure App Service?

Comment: Did you try deploying the app?

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4.8 builds on previous versions of .NET Framework 4.x by adding many new fixes and several new features while remaining a very stable product.

You can safely use ASP.NET 4.8 version in Azure App Service for your ASP.NET 4.6.1 application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/#introducing-net-framework-48